# Merge duplicate tag: Administration

Tags: support

There appears to be duplicate tag for Administration.

The duplicate has a typo, and is spelled [Adminstration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adminstration).

Can someone merge it?

Comment: Strange, 0 questions tagged with it. I was under the belief tags with no questions are automatically removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sdry mentioned in his comment, there seem to be no questions tagged [Adminstration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adminstration). There is a nightly batch job that removes unused tags, so it should disappear soon...